# Python - Correct selenium syntax can't be executed in visual studio code

Tags: python, html, selenium

Even though Python has the correct selenium syntax, in my visual studio code, I can't execute it. It is underlined in red. The cause is unknown. Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://hcs.eduro.go.kr/#/loginHome")

driver.find_element_by_id('btnConfirm2').click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.input_text_common.input_text_search').click()

time.sleep(1)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('sidolabel').click()

time.sleep(1)
elem.send_keys(keys.ARROW_DOWN) <- [An error has occurred in this point and cannot be executed]
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting

Comment: you might have forgot to import `keys`. put this as import `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- you need to [import `Keys`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys)
- `Keys` and not `keys` (first letter is in upper-case)

---

Add this to the top:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

And replace:

```
elem.send_keys(keys.ARROW_DOWN)
```

with:

```
elem.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
```